# php запрос к БД с оператором if

Tags: php, mysql

Есть запрос к таблице

```
$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM `SS_products`', $conn); // запрос на выборку
```

В таблице есть 2 столбца name и enabled, нужно выводить только те name, которых enabled не равно 0. Пробовал так, ничего не показывает вообще.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
if $row['enabled'] <>0
{
echo $row['name'].'<br>' ;// выводим данные
}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проще выбирать сразу те строки, где `enabled=1`

```
$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM `SS_products` WHERE `enabled` <> 0;', $conn)
```

Comment: Спасибо! Самое оптимальное решение

Answer (score 2):

Во первых у Вас ошибка в PHP коде. Условие нужно брать в скобки

```php
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  if ($row['enabled'] <> 0) {
    echo $row['name'] . '<br>'; // выводим данные
  }
}
```

А во вторых записи лучше отфильтровать средствами самой СУБД

```
$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM `SS_products` WHERE `enabled` <> 0', $conn);
```